# Square image crop increase image size while save to disk

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-compression

I am creating square camera app. After I capture the photo using AVCaptureStillImageOutput/AVCapturePhotoOutput while convert photo into square, square photo filesize on disk is bigger than capture photo.

Below is my code

```
func cropToBounds(width: Double, height: Double) -> UIImage {

    let contextImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: self.cgImage!)
    let contextSize: CGSize = contextImage.size

    var posX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var posY: CGFloat = 0.0
    var cgwidth: CGFloat = CGFloat(width)
    var cgheight: CGFloat = CGFloat(height)

    // See what size is longer and create the center off of that
    if contextSize.width > contextSize.height {
        posX = ((contextSize.width - contextSize.height) / 2)
        posY = 0
        cgwidth = contextSize.height
        cgheight = contextSize.height
    } else {
        posX = 0
        posY = ((contextSize.height - contextSize.width) / 2)
        cgwidth = contextSize.width
        cgheight = contextSize.width
    }

    let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: cgwidth, height: cgheight)

    // Create bitmap image from context using the rect
    let imageRef: CGImage = contextImage.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!

    // Create a new image based on the imageRef and rotate back to the original orientation
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
    return image
}
```

I also try this solution [Square Video crop with resize](https://gist.github.com/licvido/55d12a8eb76a8103c753)

Comment: increase image size means are telling about file size (bytes) or dimensions(height or width) ?

Comment: after square crop file size increase in bytes

Comment: In general, image size on disk depends very much on the compression used to store the images. Have you checked the dimensions of the images?

Comment: then you can compress image before return !!

Comment: please use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to reduce size of image save on disk